# Naples and day trips

Tags: naples

Myself and my friend are traveling to Naples in October, staying in the Naples Historical Centre. We would like to do a day trip to Pompeii, Rome and Sorrento. Are these available regularly? Do you book on the day of? Are these places fairly safe?

I would also like to ask what precautions you recommend for pickpockets? I understand they are everywhere but I am a little worried having read bad reviews for it recently in Naples. Please reassure me! I always wear a money belt under my top and only take small amounts for what I need then leave the rest in a safe. Never wear any jewellery either. I also don't take photos on a phone but on a small compact camera.

Comment: I don't think precautions against pickpockets in Naples are different from precautions against pickpockets anywhere else. Being _aware_ of the risk when you decide how to dress and where to keep things is the most important part of caution anywhere, and it sounds like you've got that in spades!

Answer (score 2):

You can get to Pompeii and Sorrento on a local commuter train (I think it's the linea 1 for both destination) from Naples central train station; I you simply need to get a ticket and hop on.

Going to Rome, you need (easier) to take a train, there's a high speed train between the 2 cities. I would book in advance. (according to google, there's a regular train that looks to take the same time ?)

Pickpockets: Just be street smart.

Comment: There are special trains on the commuter line that stop only at Naples, Pompei and Sorrento (and maybe Herculaneum). It's much better to get those than the actual local commuter train which is very slow, and can be crowded and dirty. There are also bus tours from Naples to Pompeii if you don't want to do the train.